# java Could not find or load main class from eclipse compiled code

Tags: java, command-line, path, classpath, javac

I have compiled my java code using eclipse but not it has to be deployed and a cron job has to execute it. I am trying to execute it from command line in Windows, but getting Could not find or load main class. I tried setting classpath using java -cp bin\com\pega\download\engineclasses but it still throws the same error. My folder structure looks like below

```
C:\Users\s2517457\G360_Linux\FiddlingPega
                                       |__\bin\com\pega\download\engineclasses\TestUtils.class
                                       |__\src\com\pega\download\engineclasses\TestUtils.java
```

Please let me know what should be the javac and java commands for this to work.

Comment: include the command you are executing please.

Comment: C:\Users\s2517457\G360_Linux\FiddlingPega>java -cp bin\com\pega\download\engineclasses.* com.pega.download.engineclasses.TestUtils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following command:

```
java -cp bin/ com.pega.download.engineclasses.TestUtils
```

Your are telling to java that the entire bin folder is your classpath and the main class is in the class com.pega.download.engineclasses.TestUtils

If you want to add jars as well, you must call the command like:

```
java --classpath "bin/;lib/*" com.pega.download.engineclasses.TestUtils
```

Where lib is the folder containing the Jars files

Comment: This works. But I am also trying to include jar files in lib folder located at C:\Users\s2517457\G360_Linux\FiddlingPega\lib\*.jar using 

`java -cp lib/*.jar;bin/ com.scotia.analytics.google.bigquery.Connect2BQ`

and it throws an error like below :

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/http/HttpTransport
        at com.scotia.analytics.google.bigquery.Connect2BQ.main(Connect2BQ.java:76)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)`

Comment: Try the following `java --classpath "bin/;lib/*" com.pega.download.engineclasses.TestUtils`

Comment: Works...!! Thanks a lot..!!